# Number of possible sets $A_3, \dots A_6$ such that $\{1,2\} \subseteq A_3 \subseteq \cdots \subseteq A_6 \subseteq \{1,2,3,4\}$

Tags: combinatorics

The original problem I encountered is as follows:

> Given $S = \{1,2,3,4\}$, how many possible pairs (?) of nonempty subsets $A_1, A_2, \dots, A_6$ of $S$, such that
>
> - $A_1 \cap A_2 \neq \emptyset$
> - $A_1 \cup A_2 \subseteq A_3$
> - $A_3 \subseteq \cdots \subseteq A_6$
>
> are there?

I'm interested in the case where $|A_1|= |A_2|=1$. How many possible pairs (?) of $A_3, \dots, A_6$ are there?

My approach was letting $A_1 = \{1\}$ and $A_2 = \{2\}$, and therefore $A_1 \cup A_2 = \{1,2\}$. Then, I draw all possible combinations of $A_3, \dots, A_6$ as follows:

[image: the tree diagram]

The first row is the possible choices of $A_3$, the second is $A_4$, and so on. Counting the leaves of the tree gives us $25$. I wonder if there's a way for me to find that without drawing all the possible choices. The solution for the original problem has this formula,

$$\binom{2}{0} + 4 \left(\binom{2}{1} + \binom{2}{2}\right) + 6 \binom{2}{1} \binom{1}{1} = 25$$

Where does that come from?

To recap, my questions are:

1. Is there a way to find all the possible choices without drawing the whole possibilities?
2. Where does that formula come from? How can I derive it myself?
3. How does the formula match with the tree diagram I made? (Which parts correspond with which parts?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are five places to start including the 3, and five places to start including the 4, so $5^2$ options.

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean by "five places to start including the 3"?

Comment: The 3 first appears either in $A3,A4,A5,A6$ or the final $\{1,2,3,4\}$

Comment: Oh, okay, I get it. I didn't consider the last set. And also, do you have any idea what the formula means

Comment: Not a clue.${}$