# The number of subsets of a set $S$ that fulfil certain criteria.

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

This question comes from the province-stage olympiad in my country in order to qualify for the national stage:

> Given the set $S=\{1,2,3,4\}$.The number of non-empty subsets $A_1,A_2, ..., A_6$ that fulfil these three criteria:
>
> 1. $A_1\cap A_2=\emptyset$.
> 2. $A_1\cup A_2\subseteq A_3$.
> 3. $A_3\subseteq A_4\subseteq\dots\subseteq A_6$.
>    is ...

From what I managed to conclude, $|A_1|+|A_2|\leq|A_3|$ and $|A_3|\leq|A_4|\leq|A_5|\leq|A_6|$ from the second and third criterion respectively. Then, I thought to divide the first criterion into two cases: $|A_1|=|A_2|$ and $|A_1|\neq|A_2|$. I don't know how to proceed from here. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Label each element with $0,1,2,3,4,5$ or $6$. Then put the elements into the six subsets with the following rules:

- Those with label $0$ is not in any subset
- $A_{1}$ contains those with label $1$
- $A_{2}$ contains those with label $2$
- $A_{3}$ contains those with label $1,2$ or $3$
- $A_{4}$ contains those with label $1,2,3$ or $4$
- $A_{5}$ contains those with label $1,2,3,4$ or $5$
- $A_{6}$ contains those with label $1,2,3,4,5$ or $6$

The question becomes "how many labelling has at least one $1$ and one $2$ label?

Using principle of inclusion and exclusion (PIE) we have $7^{4}-2\cdot 6^{4}+5^{4}=434$

Answer (score 3):

It seems simplest to me to put $B_2=A_2\cup A_1$ and $B_i=A_i$ for $i\in\{1,3,4,5,6\}$; we can recover the $A_i$ from the $B_i$ by $A_2=B_2\setminus B_1$ since $A_1$ and $A_2$ are disjoint and $A_i=B_i$ for $i\in\{1,3,4,5,6\}$. The question then becomes to count the chains $\emptyset\subset B_1\subset B_2\subseteq B_3\subseteq B_4\subseteq B_5\subseteq B_6$. Given such a chain we can map every $k\in\{1,2,3,4\}$ to $\min(\{i\mid 1\leq{i}\leq 6\land k\in B_i\}\cup\{7\})$, which map $f:\{1,2,3,4\}\to\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ must satisfy $\{1,2\}\subseteq\operatorname{Im}(f)$ since $A_1$ and $A_2$ have to be non-empty. Conversely any map satisfying the conditions defines a unique chain of subset $B_i$, since $B_i=\{\, k\in\{1,2,3,4\}\mid f(k)\leq{i}\,\}$.

Without the condition on $\operatorname{Im}(f)$ the number of maps is $7^4$. The number of maps without $1$ in its image is $6^4$, and so is the number without $2$ in its image. But those to sets to exclude overlap in the $5^4$ maps that have neither $1$ nor $2$ in its image, so by inclusion/exclusion the answer is $7^4-2\times6^4+5^4=434$.

Comment: Oddly, a very similar question has been asked [some time ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4195503/305862) with an "$=$" sign instead of a "$\ne$" sign for the first condition...